# Import partial Bootstrap functions

Tags: bootstrap-5

I know Bootstrap is a fabulous framework for building frontend. However, the huge size of the project might be a cons. I have a confusion of how to import partial bootstrap functions. For instance, I just want to import some components like navbar, dropdown, collapse. As for the others, I will custom them myself.
I successfully complie the css, but I have no clue with the JavaScript's part.

I am looking for some solutions to only import few functions from Bootstrap such as navbar, dropdown and collapse. as for the containers and grid, I will custom them myself. Hopefully the project size can be minimized when I add my own css and JavaScript code.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Bootstrap Docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/customize/optimize/#lean-javascript):

> For instance, assuming you’re using your own JavaScript bundler like Webpack, Parcel, or Vite, you’d only import the JavaScript you plan on using.

So you would just import the things you actually need like dropdown or collapse.

```js
import 'bootstrap/js/dist/collapse';
import 'bootstrap/js/dist/dropdown';
```